# boolean list with priority values

Tags: java, logic

I have numerous boolean variables and only one should be true in the end with the top variable having priority. I'm not sure if there's a particular word to describe this, but I'm wondering is there a cleaner way to express this in Java?

Here's the example:

```
boolean a = /*...*/;
boolean b = !a && /*...*/;
boolean c = !a && !b && /*...*/;
boolean d = !a && !b && !c && /*...*/;
boolean e = !a && !b && !c && !d;
```

So, e is true only if a through d are false, d is true only if a - c are false (and d's condition is met), etc..

Is there a better way to do this in Java? Is there a word to express this kind of logic?

Comment: It doesn't seem like a particularly useful thing to do. What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe there's a better approach to that.

Comment: It's a process model that a purchase order goes through. It goes through "A" until it meets a certain criteria, then it goes to "B" until another criteria, then C, then D, etc.. So this will determine which table the order is displayed on.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Chain-of-responsibility design pattern. With this pattern you assemble a chain of processing objects and pass a request to it. Processing starts at the head of the chain. The current chain object decides whether or not to process the command. If it doesn't process the command, it passes it to the next object on the chain.

Suppose you have 4 criteria, CA, CB, CC and CD. You would have 5 processing objects, 4 of them would correspond to those 4 criteria and the other would accept anything, that is, wouldn't check for any condition.

Here's an example, adapted from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

```
abstract class Processor {
    protected Processor successor;

    public void setSuccessor(Processor successor) {
        this.successor = successor;
    }

    abstract protected boolean checkCondition(OrderRequest request);

    abstract protected void execute(OrderRequest request);

    public void processRequest(OrderRequest request){
        if(checkCondition(request)) {
            execute(request);
        } else if(successor != null) {
            successor.processRequest(request);
        }
    }
}

public class CAProcessor extends Processor {
    protected boolean checkCondition(OrderRequest request) {
        return request.TotalWithVAT > 100 && request.getNPurchasedItems() > 20;
    }

    protected void execute(OrderRequest request) {
        //Here you can call some method, set some instance variable, etc...
        request.setTable(1);
    }
}

public class DefaultProcessor extends Processor {
    protected boolean checkCondition(OrderRequest request) {
        return true;
    }

    protected void execute(OrderRequest request) {
        request.setTable(5);
    }
}
```

To assemble the chain you can do something like

```
Processor ca = new CAProcessor();
Processor cb = new CBProcessor();
...
Processor defaultProcessor = new DefaultProcessor();
ca.setSuccessor(cb);
...
cd.setSuccessor(defaultProcessor);
```

To execute

```
ca.execute(request);
```